# Using a select clause in a case statement in TD

Tags: sql, teradata

Is it possible to somehow use a select clause in a case statement in TD (rather than doing a join)?

I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   , count(*)
   , (CASE WHEN id IN ANY (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PARTICIPANTS_TABLE)                             
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 
      end) AS participant 
FROM EVERYONE_TABLE
GROUP BY id
```

The error I get is "Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE expression."

Comment: The syntax is `id = ANY (...)` or `id IN (...)`

Answer (score 5):

You should change the SELECT to a Scalar Subquery

```
SELECT 
   id 
   , COUNT(*)
   , (CASE WHEN id = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM PARTICIPANTS_TABLE AS p
                      WHERE p.id = e.id)
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 
      END) AS participant 
FROM EVERYONE_TABLE AS e
GROUP BY id
```

But a basic rule i always follow is to avoid Scalar Subqueries in the Select list, in my experience they tend to have a bad optimization.

I would rewrite it to an Outer Join (imho this is a main reason why people write Scalar Subqueries, in most cases they simply hide an Outer Join):

```
SELECT 
   t1.id 
   , COUNT(*)
   , COUNT(t2.ID) AS participant 
FROM EVERYONE_TABLE AS t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PARTICIPANTS_TABLE) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Plus this syntax is easier to understand, at least for me :-)

Comment: What may be less obvious is that the COUNT(t2.ID) will ignore the NULL values returned by the OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work with the right syntax:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM PARTICIPANTS_TABLE) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         end) AS participant;
```

The `distinct` is unnecessary, though:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT ID FROM PARTICIPANTS_TABLE) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
         end) AS participant;
```